# Mongoose sorting by populated field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sorting, mongoose

In my Task schema I have fields like this:

```
{
  name: String
},
{
  user: ObjectID
}
```

I need to sort tasks. If I want to do it by `name` field it's easy:

```
await Tasks.find().sort({name: 1})
```

That works. But the problem is when I want to sort by `user.name`. To get fields from User I can populate them, so:

```
await Tasks.find().populate('user', 'name').sort({'user.name': 1})
```

And it doesn't work. I cannot sort by fields added by `populate` function. I've been searching a lot in documentation and in other users' questions. I've found that I can pass sorting option to `populate` function but it doesn't work also. I guess it sort fields in populated field.

When I've tried to use aggregate with lookup like this:

```
Tasks.aggregate([{ $lookup: {
{
   from: 'User',
   localField: 'user',
   foreignField: '_id',
   as: 'someField'
 }}}])
```

it returns `someField: []`

Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `aggregate` query, you should reference your collection with it's real name, **NOT** with the model name. So, instead of `from: 'User'`, it should be `from: 'users'`:

```js
Tasks.aggregate([
  { 
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      localField: 'user',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'user'
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      user: { $first: '$user' }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      'user.name': 1 
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really it. Now I get my values from user collection in user field, but when I add $sort, user field disappears from output and sorting doesn't work...

Comment: Also user id is missing now

Comment: Did you try my code or your code?

Comment: Your code and change only field names. When I sort by field 'name' everything works. But when I try to sort by field created by $set it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Everything works as it should. I screw up. Thank you a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.